# How do I "run" a RavenDb Test?

Tags: ravendb

I've created a project with the help of this:

http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/samples/raven-tests/createraventests

And this might be a stupid question. But how do I run the tests to se they fail or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is an xUnit test. You run this text with the xUnit test runner inside Visual Studio, as you'll run any xUnit test:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099